# Moderation with a latent variable in AMOS

Tags: interaction, model, structural-equation-modeling, amos

I am trying to create an `AMOS` SEM model between Childhood Traumas (CT) and Borderline Personality Disorder (BDL), and the Behavioral İnhibition System (BİS) will be moderating this relationship. It will be a full structural model, so I will add CT as a latent variable predicting its 6 subscales (trauma types) and BDL as a latent variable predicting its 8 scale items. Moderator variable BİS will join the model as a latent variable , predicting its 7 scale items. To draw this moderation analysis, I need to create interaction terms. Since CT and BİS both latent, to create the interaction terms, I need to multiply all of their observable variables, meaning there will be a latent variable called CTxBİS that is predicting a total of 6*7=42 observable variables, interaction terms like CT1xBİS1, CT1xBİS2, CT1xBİS3 and so on. The model fit will probably be poor since it is too complex.

*Doing moderation analysis in `AMOS` shouldn't be this complicated and hard.*

[image: The Ideal Moderation Analysis]

I could use the matched pairs method to simplify the model, but it would require me to create all 42 interaction terms and then select the top 6 of them (I want to have at least 1 interaction term for each subscale of CT) via choosing the interaction terms with the top standardized regression weight. I am following [Collier's video on the Matched Pairs Method.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRN5TvYQuRk)

[image: Reduced Interaction Variables via Matched Pairs Method]

If I were to go a bit too far, I would first use the parceling method to reduce the observed variables of BİS, reducing them to 3 observable variables (BİSf1, BİSf2, and BİSf3). After that, I will create CTxBİS latent variable that predicts 6*3=18 interaction terms. To reduce the interaction terms' count, I will proceed with the matched pair method and will choose the interaction terms with the top standardized regression weight. I will be careful to choose one interaction for each subscale of CT, so I will still have 6 interaction terms (this part is debatable; maybe I can go for 3 interaction terms for each subfactor of BİS (BİSf1, BİSf2, and BİSf3). See the picture under:

[image: Am I losing it?]

So the main question is, "Is there a better and easier way to do moderation analysis with latent moderation variables in `AMOS`?" and the second one is, "Using the matched pairs method with the parceling method is too much?"